# Mudar Dados dos TD de uma Tabela

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Ola. Tenho uma Tabela onde td  tem um ID com o cod de um produto, por exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para pegar esse ID e mudar as Informações dos  sem precisar atualizar a pagina?

Eu estou Usando Ajax para fazer as buscas no banco de dados, e tenho um Botão chamado Editar, onde vai editar a linha clicada, a ideia é que quando salvar a edição, mude somente a linha que foi editada sem a necessidade de atualizar a tabela td, por isso eu criei esse ID na tr para ter uma forma mais fácil de editar a linha.

alguém poderia me ajudar.

Ajax Editar:

```js
$('#EditarPro').click(function() {

            var ECod = $("#ECodigo").val();
            var Edesc = $("#EDesc").val();
            var Eqtd = $("#EQtd").val();
            var Evalor = $("#EValor").val();

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "editar.php",
                data: {
                    cod: ECod,
                    desc: Edesc,
                    qtn: Eqtd,
                    valor: Evalor
                }
            }).done(function(resposta) {
                // alert(resposta);
                // GerarTabela();
                if (resposta == '"Cadastro Com Sucesso!"') {
                    MudaLinha(Ecod);
                    $("#FecharModal").trigger('click');
                } else {
                    alert('falha ao Cadastrar');
                }
            }).fail(function() {
                $(".FecharModal").trigger('click');
                alert('falha ao Cadastrar');
                GerarTabela();
            });
        });
```

Função MudaLinha()

```js
function MudaLinha(cod) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "Select.php",
                data: {
                    cod: cod,
                }
            }).done(function(resposta) {
                resposta = JSON.parse(resposta);

            }).fail(function() {
                console.log('falha ao Procurar');
            });
        }
```

Comment: Não sei se vc já procurou, mas há plugins de jQuery que fazem previamente isso

Comment: Por isso estou aqui, pq procurei e não achei

Comment: *"Como posso fazer para pegar esse ID e mudar as Informações"* `$('#tr27').html('aqui vai o conteúdo que quer mudar')`. E vc disse que procurou e não achou, chegou a ver o [datatables](https://datatables.net/)? Faz isso que precisa, passar dados e ele montar os valores em tabela

Comment: Certo o datatables eu conheço porem não posso usar ele aqui ainda não

Comment: Então vc já até encontrou, "só não pode" usar um deles... Existe uma penca desses plugins: https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/In-place%20Editing/

Comment: Mas desde que surgiram frameworks como angular, react, vue,. knockout, etc e etc, acho que editar a dom para esses casos bem démodé...

Comment: Jeito "fácil" de resolver: para cada TR que vc criou, cria 2 - um como vc fez e outro com o form de update, o botão de edit faz esse outro TR ser exibido, ao submeter o form, aguardar pela resposta de sucesso, em caso de sucesso, atualizar o TR de dados. Para saber o que/como atualizar vc pode criar um atributo nos inputs com o nome do TD que deverá ser atualizado - ex: data-updateelement=<id do TD a ser atualizado>

Comment: Caso queira uma resposta concreta baseada nisso diz e eu tento elaborar mais para tirar uma eventual dúvida.

Comment: Seria mais simples utilizar o load: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp
Veja se entendeu, se não entendeu eu faço um exemplo aqui